# Creating Temporary Filepage in Php - Possible?

Tags: php

I was wondering if it's possible to use php to create a file with a specific name that would last 30 seconds, and then delete its self. I looked at the tmpfile and tmpnme functions but I must not know how to use them correctly.

I would like to click a button on webpage A, and then have information shown on webpage B for 30 seconds. Once the 30 seconds is up, the information would change or clear out entirely.

Possible?

Comment: Yes, sure - this is possible, but why not "just" use a single page with some querystring thats unique to the user and validate the page?

Comment: See the [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341)

Comment: Its actually used for a program to look at. I click a button, and something on a seperate page says "shutdown" that the program reads and will automatically go through its shutdown process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP can easily create a temporary file for you, but it'll be up to you to actually remove it after the 30 seconds is up. PHP isn't a scheduler, though it can schedule things for you via `cron` or `at`.

Your best bet would be to embed some extra code into the PHP script as it's built to specify an expiry time, which the generated script can check when it's first started:

```
<?php

$expires = ...insert some timestamp value here...;

if ($expires < time()) {
    unlink(__FILE__);
    header("Location: somewhere else");
    exit();
}

... do whatever you need to here ...
```

That'll take care of the script terminating itself. But if the script is never accessed outside of the 30 second window, it wouldn't clean itself up, so you'd still need an external job to go in and do some periodic housecleaning.

Comment: This is very close to what I was imagining but unfrotuntley a little over my head. My idea was to use forms and POST, and post to a separate page. The issue is, after 30 seconds I do need the info to terminate or change back to a default value. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can also have the parent script add an `at` job to schedule an external removal task to kill the generated/child script. however, `at` and `cron` can schedule down to the minute level only, not seconds, so you can't guarantee that the child script gets nuked after exactly 30 seconds. But with the external removal and the internal time check, you can simulate it easily. The other alternative is to fork(), and have the child sleep for 30 seconds then unlink the child script.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file like an XML for example. Add a new node and time stamp it. Then your website can load the file and based on the timestamp show the node that hasn't expired. You don't have to delete the file just don't show the old data. You can also when loading the node, delete the old ones to keep the file from getting large.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea where I could see an example or script of something like this?